# Eclipse unable to create html/jsp file

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, error-handling

I am using Eclipse Kepler javaee version. When I try to create a HTML or JSP, its showing   [this](http://postimg.org/image/gqmovguzl/) error and if I create a file its getting created. This problem occurs after I update eclipse. How do I fix this error? The error am getting in my log file is,

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-10-15 14:48:43.777
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.internal.wizard.FacetModuleCoreSupportDelegate.getAcceptableRootPaths(FacetModuleCoreSupportDelegate.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.internal.wizard.FacetModuleCoreSupport.getAcceptableRootPaths(FacetModuleCoreSupport.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.internal.wizard.NewHTMLFileWizardPage.validatePage(NewHTMLFileWizardPage.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.handleEvent(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.misc.ResourceAndContainerGroup.handleEvent(ResourceAndContainerGroup.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:2974)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4752)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4614)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2597)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3473)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:2252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.misc.ResourceAndContainerGroup.setResource(ResourceAndContainerGroup.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.setFileName(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.internal.wizard.NewHTMLFileWizardPage.createControl(NewHTMLFileWizardPage.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.wizards.WizardShortcutAction.run(WizardShortcutAction.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: this exception shows that you are trying to store wrong object in your array and could you please explain what is the difference in creating a file in a project and and creating a file without project

Comment: I havent mentioned am creating a file outside project, sorry for my weak english. If I right-click on the folder where I have to create a html/jsp file its shows options and in that moves to New and then if I click file, a file creating UI appears and if I click html/jsp nothing happens. [Image](http://postimg.org/image/3nfmjl7vp/) to illustrate.

Comment: tell me the version no for kepler

Comment: Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229 And this is my [about eclipse](http://postimg.org/image/a593atcoj/).

Comment: Check the Error Log view or the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is more details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are creating a JSP in a folder that should not have JSP files.

The most like cause is that, the folder that you are adding the JSP file is not specified in the Web Deployment Assembly. The Web Deployment Assembly can be found when you right click your project and select 'properties'. Make sure you specify WEB-INF's parent folder.

I had this error once and I resolved it with the above mentioned step.